# Error showing facebook install app on BlackBerry,

Tags: php, facebook, mobile, oauth

I have a facebook app that I use with a mobile site, I need the user to install the app, so I made this code for redirecting users to the install app site:

```
  $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_about_me,user_hometown,user_checkins,publish_checkins',
                'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl'],
                'display'       => 'wap'
            )
    );
```

The problem is that facebook will not support the "wap" render anymore after July 1, so I change it to "touch".
Now the problem is that when I try to install or login from a BlackBerry 8520 it throws me an error saying me to try again later.
I also have an error log but it dosent save any error.
I dont know if the problem is that the BlackBerry has the javascript support off by default or that the device is not touch.

I can use "page" or "popup" instead of "touch", but then the install dialog will take really long if its not connected via wifi.

Here is facebook official infromation about this subject:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php sdk version 2, upgrade it to version 3 (new version).

this may be solve your problem.

More Info : [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in)